# Razor partial views break css

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is very wired problem to salve as to explain. Before I go to try to fix CSS I wan't to be sure that I am doing right what I am doing here.
I have one index page that contain few smaller views. Each smaller view has it's own model classes. I render smaller views like this:

```
<div id="left" style="width: 205px; float: left; ">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Controller3");}
    </div>
    <div id="center" style="width: 540px; float: left;">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Controller2");}
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="width: 205px; float: left;">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Controller3");}
    </div>
...
```

Index view contains:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
  ....
```

And view renders fine. But if I remove from smaller index view "Layout = null;" then my view big break somehow. All elements loose it's positions. Now: 
- Is this "Layout = null;" line very important for something here?
- When one view contain smaller view like this should I return from Action methods View() or PartialView()?
- Is there any other approach to make big view from few smaller or this is the good way as I doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't add `Layout = null` to the child view, each child view will render your entire `_Layout.cshtml` around it.

Returning `Partial(...)` from the child action will also suppress the layout.